# Codeigniter: Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: function, codeigniter-2

I hope somebody can help me with this function:

```
function ageAll(){   
    $this->db->select_avg('Column1');
    $query = $this->db->get('table1');
    echo $this->db->last_query().'<br />';
    return $query->Column1;

 }
```

I see in the echo that the query is okay but I got still the error:

**A PHP Error was encountered**
**Severity: Notice**
**Message: Trying to get property of non-object**
**Filename: models/Testmodel.php**
**Line Number: 36**

I Hope somebody can provide me an solution, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a query object, which does not have Column1 as a property.  You need to return a result.  that can be either the first_row() method, or the result() method.  first_row() seems appropriate in your case.

try:

```
return $query->first_row()->Column1;
```

if you want to make the code slightly more readable you could consider.

```
function ageAll(){   
    return $this->db->select_avg('Column1')
                 ->from('table1')
                 ->get()
                 ->first_row()
                 ->Column1;

 }
```